# Java String.split multiple character delimiter

Tags: java, regex

I would like to parse just one long line from file based on " and , and [ and ] and { and }

For e.g

```
{"ColumnTypes":"int32","fstring32","int32"],"ColumnNames":"ProductId",","ProductName","Quantity"]}
```

I actually need two different array from this line column types and column names. I tried `string.split("\\W")` but it is not working.

Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you're 100% certain that these characters will not be a part of your string literals?

Comment: All those braces and brackets are heavily unbalanced. Are they really like that? If they aren't, this almost looks like JSON, so you could parse your string much more sensibly.

Comment: Hi @TimPietzcker thanks a lot for the input. Yes it may be JSON I am not sure can you please guide me how can I parse it. It is written inside plain schema text file.

Comment: Try http://json.org/java/, that should contain all the information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split on *multiple* `\\W` chars (add a `+`), but first trim off such chars from the front, so you don't get a blank first element:

```
String[] array = string.replaceAll("^\\W+", "").split("\\W+");
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker No need. `split()` drops all trailing blanks from the result. To include the blanks you must call `split()` with a second parameter of `-1` (or a very large number).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (with regex) would be to allow more than one non-word character to match:

```
string.split("\\W+")
```

Comment: Try using regex notation `/\W+/` instead of `"\\W+"`

Comment: Whoops.  No you are right.  I had a brain fart.  Was thinking JavaScript

Comment: Is groovy notation also :)